# TIKZ coordinate from equation

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a linear equation between two variables, say `b(a)=2a+3`, I'd like to use the equation to determine where to place a marker, as a function. For example:

`\node at (0,b{1}) {};`

would put it at (0,5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use calculations directly, e.g.

```
\node at (0, 2*1 + 3) {};
```

or declare a function in a `\tikzset` or the optional argument to a `tikzpicture` with

```
declare function={b(\x) = 2*\x + 3;}
```

and then use

```
\node at (0, {b(1)}) {};
```

Note that you use parentheses for the function argument, and you need a pair of curly brackets around the entire y-coordinate to "hide" the parens in the function call from the parser, otherwise the `)` for the function will be confused for the `)` for the coordinate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  declare function={ % these functions are available everywhere
    a(\x) = 2*\x + 3; % note ending semicolons
    b(\x) = 5*\x - 2;
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={c(\x) = -3*\x;} % this is only available in this tikzpicture
]
\node (a) at (0, {a(0)}) {a};
\node (b) at (0, {b(0)}) {b};
\node (c) at (0, {c(0)}) {c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```